# Save for Web with Layer Mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, mask

I have an image which has a layer mask so that the image fades to transparent. However when I try to export the image (Save for Web) as a PNG the layer mask is lost. What am I doing wrong? Can this be done?

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure you don't have something like Background layer still in the document?

Comment: Reset your Photoshop preferences and ensure you don't have a matte color selected in save for web.

Comment: Either there's a bg underneath your layer, or the transparency option isn't checked when you're saving for web. As someone else mentioned, make sure it's png 24 and not 8. 8 has transparency as well, but it's low enough quality that it's basically never worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have it set to PNG-24, not PNG-8. Also confirm that the Transparency option is ticked and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, however it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: In your save for web pop-up, can you see the transparent squares in the background of your image?

Comment: [Input Image](http://i.imgur.com/Jw5WDDO.png)  
[Output Image](http://i.imgur.com/l16n0A0.png)

Comment: I really don't know the cause, but just to help you trouble shoot, when you click the preview button at the bottom of the save for web dialog, it gives you a preview in the browser. Does that say 'Transparency on' in the settings summary on the browser page?

Comment: It does indeed. However the image still doesn't look right... Thanks anyway.